# Inverse Hyperbolic Functions in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

What I want is to plot a function that includes an inverse hyperbolic sine in it.
This is my code/

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{arcsinh}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [restrict z to domain=0:100,zmax=200]
\addplot3 [surf, samples=30,domain=-155:205,y domain=0:10, z buffer=sort]
({sin(x)*y},{cos(x)*y},{60.13+1.9*tan(\arcsinh y)-15.69*cos(1.794+y-tanh(0.9074*y))}); 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this comes up with an error saying that:

```
Argument of \pgfplotsforeachungrouped@ has an extra }.
```

meaning the `}` before the `\end{axis}`. But also deleting it does no good (And I know it is needed there.)

Comment: You need to define the equation for `arcsinh`: `\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={arcsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}`

Comment: Thanks Jake for the quick response but I get the same error message... I added the line you gave me just before the \begin command... Is that right? Should I change sth else?

Comment: LaTeX doesn't know higher mathematics. `;-)` Define the function for `pgf` and remove the backslash in the call to it: it should be `(arcsinh(y))` and not `(\arcsinh y)`.

Comment: @Jake an answer?

Comment: With Jake's equation and egreg's advice it works fine! Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 10):

[`pgf`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) doesn't know about `arcsinh` by default, but as mentioned in the comments, you can easily teach it, by using

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={arcsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}
```

This formula is quite easy to derive if you use the definition of the `sinh` function

```
sinh(x) = (e^x - e^(-x))/2
```

I noticed that you used the line

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{arcsinh}
```

which will be useful if you wish to *typeset* the inverse `sinh` function, for example as `\arcsinh(x)`, but it is not the same thing as declaring it for `pgf`.

Here's a complete MWE to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={arcsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [restrict z to domain=0:100,zmax=200]
        \addplot3 [surf, 
            samples=30,
            domain=-155:205,
            y domain=0:10, 
            z buffer=sort
        ]
        ({sin(x)*y},{cos(x)*y},{60.13+1.9*tan(arcsinh(y))-15.69*cos(1.794+y-tanh(0.9074*y))}); 
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DonutE.Knot very nice, congratulations! It seems funny that you haven't received the `PSTricks` gold badge, yet :)

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-)